# Terminal hangs while I use `$ pass insert [..]`

Tags: terminal, passwords, password-management

This post is about the utility `pass`. It works well for me except when I tried to use

```
$ pass insert Email/gmail/myname
```

My terminal gives the prompt

```
Enter password for Email/gmail/myname: _
```

and hangs, so far no keystrokes affect it, except `Ctrl-C` to stop the program. Interesting enough, the program did create the directories `~/.local/share/password-store/Email/gmail/`. Anyone had the same problem before?

(I'm using `pass` v1.7.3 on an arch.)

Comment: I have no experience with the tool, not at all; but the manual states `pass insert` reads from stdin. Are you sure it hangs? Maybe it just waits for input.

Comment: Thanks for reaching.. I could not type in anything. Any keystrokes do not work so far except `Ctrl-C`..

Comment: Did you get the prompt (`Enter password for...`)?

Comment: Yes! My bad, I should have described that details! Edited.

Comment: Well, it's normal you cannot see what you type in this line. The tool will accept your input after you hit Enter. Please confirm explicitly that Enter does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

For interactive insert, the `enter` key indicates that you're done typing the password:

```
$ pass insert test
Enter password for test:   [keystrokes: asdf<enter>]
Retype password for test:  [keystrokes: asdf<enter>]

$ pass test
adsf
```

Additionally, with `--echo` or `-e` you can take input through stdin from a pipe.

For example, I make the entry `testo` with password `hello world`:

```
$ echo "hello world" | pass insert --echo testo
[main b451b23] Add given password for testo to store.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 testo.gpg

$ pass testo
hello world
```

That only works for single lines though. For multiline input, use the `--multiline` flag instead of `--echo`.

```
$ man pass
$ echo "password123" > passfile.txt
$ echo "Email: me@example.com" >> passfile.txt
$ cat passfile.txt | pass insert --multiline test
Enter contents of test and press Ctrl+D when finished:

[main e1acd8e] Add given password for test to store.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 test.gpg

$ pass test
password123
Email: me@example.com
```

Documentation from the manual page doesn't mention pressing `enter` to terminate input, maybe I'll email the [dev mailing list](https://lists.zx2c4.com/mailman/listinfo/password-store) about it. Here's the current `man pass`:

```
       insert [ --echo, -e | --multiline, -m ] [ --force, -f ] pass-name
              Insert  a  new  password  into the password store called pass-name. This will read the new password from standard in. If --echo or -e is not
              specified, disable keyboard echo when the password is entered and confirm the password by asking for it twice. If --multiline or -m is spec‐
              ified,  lines will be read until EOF or Ctrl+D is reached. Otherwise, only a single line from standard in is read. Prompt before overwriting
              an existing password, unless --force or -f is specified. This command is alternatively named add.
```